# Function that sorts a linked List

Tags: c, list, sorting

So i wrote a code that takes in a string from a text file, proccesses it and saves it into a doubly linked list, so far so good, however, now i want to sort the list by the how often the letters occured in the list.
The list is very simple (for now :D):

```
"ABBBCC"
```

i expect the output to be:

```
B C A
```

as

B appeared 3 times,
C appeared 2 times and
A appeared only once

however i get this as an output

```
C A B
```

so this is my struct,

```
typedef struct LNodeStruct LNode;
struct LNodeStruct
{
 unsigned char value;
 int freq;
 LNode* next;
 LNode* prev;
};
```

value = the letter itself
freq = how often the letter appeared

This is the function, it takes in the linked List called "List", runs to the first node and compares the first node with node->next then swaps it if the first node is smaller:

```
LNode* insertSorted(LNode* List)
{

while (List != NULL && List->prev != NULL)
    {
        List = List->prev;
    }

for(LNode* i = List; i->next != NULL; i = i->next)
    {
        for (LNode* j = i->next; j != NULL; j = j->next)
            {
                if(i->freq < j->freq)
                {
                    int temp = i->value;
                    i->value = j->value;
                    j->value = temp;
                }

            }

    }
return (List);
}
```

Can anyone help where my error might be. I suspect one of the two for loops in the fuction.

Comment: You are only swapping the `value`. You need to swap the `freq` too.

Comment: that was quick, thank you very much, that worked, is there a way to swap both nodes as a whole? as in create a temp node, save i in that node and so on?

Comment: Of course - just write a `swap(LNodeStruct&, LNodeStruct&)` function and use that. Remember it needs to change `i->prev->next`, `j->next->prev` etc. as well as the pointers in `i` and `j` themselves.

Comment: It is possible to rearrange the nodes in a different order by changing the links.

Comment: @Ahmed Sabti What is this while (List != NULL && List->prev != NULL)
    {
        List = List->prev;
    }  ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> that was quick, thank you very much, that worked, is there a way to swap both nodes as a whole? as in create a temp node, save i in that node and so on? –
> Ahmed Sabti

To swap the entire struct contents, replace the swap code with:

```
LNode temp = *i;
*j = *i;
*j = temp;
```

**Edit:** But ... As John pointed out below, the above isn't sufficient. We have to preserve the links. We *could* just copy element by element *except* for the links, but the simplest way is to do the whole struct copy but save/restore the links:

```
// preserve the link pointers
LNode *temp_i = i->next;
LNode *temp_j = j->next;

// swap all contents
LNode temp = *i;
*j = *i;
*j = temp;

// restore the link pointers
i->next = temp_i;
j->next = temp_j;
```

---

You're swapping the entire struct contents, due to the nature of your sort. That's fine, but it wouldn't scale as well if your struct had (e.g.) `int array[1000000];` in it.

However, a linked list lends itself very well to a mergesort. With that, you *can* just swap the links.

Here's some mergesort code for a linked list that I have lying around. It's part of a much bigger lib that I have, so it won't be directly compilable.

It uses a separate struct for a list vs. a node.

Since it's from my personal collection, I have my own conventions. `slh_p` is a pointer to a list struct. `slk_p` is a pointer to an element struct.

It may give you some ideas:

```
// ovrlib/sls -- singly linked list sort

#include <ovrlib/slk.h>

#include <stdio.h>

// _slhsort -- sort list
void
_slhsort(slh_p slh,slkcmp_p cmp)
{

    // NOTE: this is a separate routine so we can add the code below for a
    // doubly linked list
    _slhsortgo(slh,cmp);

#if 0
    slk_p prev;
    slk_p cur;

    // do final fixup of back chain pointers
    // FIXME/CAE -- doing a single pass here is _probably_ faster than doing
    // it in the merge step [only to toss it away]
    prev = NULL;
    for (cur = slh->slh_head;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->slk_next) {
        cur->slk_prev = prev;
        prev = cur;
    }
#endif
}

// _slhsortgo -- sort list
void
_slhsortgo(slh_p slhi,slkcmp_p cmp)
{
    slh_t slhlhs;
    slh_t slhrhs;

    do {
        // trivial case (i.e. empty list or list with _single_ element)
        if (slhi->slh_curcnt < 2)
            break;

        // split the list
        _slhsortspl(slhi,&slhlhs,&slhrhs);

        // sort left half
        _slhsortgo(&slhlhs,cmp);

        // sort right half
        _slhsortgo(&slhrhs,cmp);

        // merge them
        _slhsortmrg(slhi,&slhlhs,&slhrhs,cmp);
    } while (0);
}

// _slhsortspl -- split up list
void
_slhsortspl(slh_p slhi,slh_p slhlhs,slh_p slhrhs)
{
    slhoff_t lhscnt;
    slk_p cur;
    slk_p prev;
    slk_p next;

    // NOTE: we leave slhi's slh_curcnt intact as it is invariant across the
    // merge

    // get the split point
    lhscnt = slhi->slh_curcnt;
    lhscnt /= 2;

    // set the counts
    slhlhs->slh_curcnt = lhscnt;
    slhrhs->slh_curcnt = slhi->slh_curcnt - lhscnt;

    // NOTES:
    // (1) because we're doing half the list and the list has at least two, we
    //     _know_ "cur" will _never_ be null
    // (2) the loop _must_ execute at least _once_
    // (3) thus, we know that "prev" will be non-null at the end
    // (4) and, we know that "next" will be _valid_ at the end
    prev = NULL;
    for (cur = slhi->slh_head;  lhscnt > 0;  --lhscnt, cur = next) {
        next = cur->slk_next;
        prev = cur;
    }

    // finish the left list:
    //   (1) set the head
    //   (2) set the tail
    //   (3) break the chain pointer to the right half
    slhlhs->slh_head = slhi->slh_head;
    slhlhs->slh_tail = prev;
    prev->slk_next = NULL;

    // finish the right list:
    //   (1) set the head
    //   (2) set the tail
    slhrhs->slh_head = next;
    slhrhs->slh_tail = slhi->slh_tail;
}

// _slhsortmrg -- merge the two halves
void
_slhsortmrg(slh_p slho,slh_p slhlhs,slh_p slhrhs,slkcmp_p cmp)
{
    slk_p cur;
    slk_p lhs;
    slk_p rhs;
    slk_p prev;
    slk_p tail;
    int stopflg;

    lhs = slhlhs->slh_head;
    rhs = slhrhs->slh_head;

    prev = NULL;
    stopflg = 0;

    // NOTE: we are guaranteed to execute this once, so we always set the head
    // and we will always have a non-null "prev" value
    while (1) {
        // stop when [at least] one of the lists runs dry
        if (stopflg)
            break;

        // left list element is lower
        if (cmp(lhs,rhs) <= 0) {
            cur = lhs;
            lhs = lhs->slk_next;
            stopflg = (lhs == NULL);
        }

        // right list element is lower
        else {
            cur = rhs;
            rhs = rhs->slk_next;
            stopflg = (rhs == NULL);
        }

        // set the output list head
        if (prev == NULL)
            slho->slh_head = cur;

        // append to the output list
        else
            prev->slk_next = cur;

        // remember the previous/last element we added to the output list
        prev = cur;
    }

    // select the remainder (i.e. the non-empty list)
    // there will be only one, at most, and we can have none
    do {
        cur = NULL;

        // left list has all remaining higher values
        if (lhs != NULL) {
            cur = lhs;
            tail = slhlhs->slh_tail;
            break;
        }

        // right list has all remaining higher values
        if (rhs != NULL) {
            cur = rhs;
            tail = slhrhs->slh_tail;
            break;
        }

        // both lists have been exhausted [equally]:
        //   (1) nothing more to append
        //   (2) we already know the tail
        tail = prev;
    } while (0);

    // append the remainder to the output list
    prev->slk_next = cur;

    // set the tail of the output list
    // the tail's next pointer is already null
    slho->slh_tail = tail;
}
```

Here is the relevant `.h` file:

```
// ovrlib/slk.h -- singly linked list control

#ifndef _ovrlib_slk_h_
#define _ovrlib_slk_h_

#include <ovrinc/ovrtypes.h>
#include <ovrinc/ovrinl.h>
#include <ovrinc/ovrstruct.h>
#include <ovrinc/ovrptr.h>

CDEFBEGIN

typedef long slhoff_t;                  // dynamic array offset

#define _SLKDEF(_typ) \
    u32 slk_stat;                   /* status */ \
    TYP_P(_typ) slk_next            /* link to next element */

#define SLKDEF(_typ) \
    _MSTRUCT(_typ)

#define SLH_P(_typa) \
    TYP_P(_typa)
#define SLK_P(_typ) \
    TYP_P(_typ)

#define SLHDEFX(_typa,_typ) \
    MFORWARD(_typ); \
    MFORWARD(_typa); \
    _MSTRUCT(_typa) { \
        u32 slh_stat;                   /* status */ \
        slhoff_t slh_itmsiz;            /* item size */ \
        slhoff_t slh_grow;              /* number of elements to grow */ \
        TYP_P(_typa) slh_pool;          /* free pool chain pointer */ \
        const char *slh_tag;            /* list name */ \
        /**/ \
        TYP_P(_typ) slh_head;           /* head pointer */ \
        TYP_P(_typ) slh_tail;           /* tail pointer */ \
        /**/ \
        slhoff_t slh_curcnt;            /* current active count */ \
        /**/ \
        void (*slh_yldproc)(TYP_P(_typa));  /* yield subroutine */ \
        void *slh_yldptr;               /* yield control */ \
        int slh_yldchunk;               /* yield chunk control */ \
    }

#define SLHYLDPROC(_slh,_proc) \
    typeof(_slh->slh_yldproc) _proc = _slh->slh_yldproc

#define SLHDEF(_typ) \
    SLHDEFX(_typ,_typ)

// generic definition
SLHDEFX(slh,slk);
SLKDEF(slk) {
    _SLKDEF(slk);
    void *slk_xtra;                     // link to data
};

// initialize for yield loop
#define YLDCNTINIT(_slh,_yldcnt) \
    do { \
        if (_slh->slh_stat & SLHDONE) { \
            _yldcnt = 0; \
            break; \
        } \
        _yldcnt = _slh->slh_yldchunk; \
        if (_yldcnt != 0) \
            break; \
        _yldcnt = -1; \
    } while (0)

// bump down yield count
#define YLDCNTINC(_yldcnt) \
    if (_yldcnt > 0) \
        --_yldcnt

#define SLKALLOC        (1u << 31)      // allocated item
#define SLHPOOL         (1u << 30)      // list is free pool
#define SLHINITED       (1u << 29)      // list is inited
#define SLHDONE         (1u << 28)      // list is done
#define SLHDIRTY        (1u << 27)      // list is "dirty"

#define SLH(_vp)        CAST(slh_p,_vp)
#define SLK(_vp)        CAST(slk_p,_vp)

#define slhsetup(_slh,_siz,_grow)   VP(_slhsetup(SLH(_slh),_siz,_grow))
#define slhattach(_pool,_slh)       _slhattach(SLH(_pool),SLH(_slh))
#define slhgrow(_slh)               _slhgrow(SLH(_slh))

#define slknew(_slh)                VP(_slknew(SLH(_slh)))
#define slkrls(_slh,_slk)           _slkrls(SLH(_slh),SLK(_slk))

#define slkpush(_slh,_pnew)         VP(_slkpush(SLH(_slh),SLK(_pnew)))
#define slkshift(_slh,_slk)         VP(_slkshift(SLH(_slh),SLK(_slk)))

#define slhrls(_slh)                _slhrls(SLH(_slh))
#define slhkill(_slh)               _slhkill(SLH(_slh))

#define slhsort(_slh,_cmp)          _slhsort(SLH(_slh),_cmp)
typedef int (*slkcmp_p)(const void *,const void *);

// simple forward scan
#define SLHFORALL(_slh,_slk) \
    CASTEQ(_slk,_slh->slh_head);  _slk != NULL;  CASTEQ(_slk,_slk->slk_next)

// shift forward scan
#define SLHFORALL_SHIFT(_slh,_slk) \
    _slk = slkshift(_slh,NULL);  _slk != NULL;  _slk = slkshift(_slh,NULL)

// shift forward scan
#define SLHFORALL_SHIFT_RELEASE(_slh,_slk) \
    _slk = slkshift(_slh,NULL);  _slk != NULL;  _slk = slkshift(_slh,_slk)

// continuation forward scan
#define _SLHFORALL(_slh,_slk) \
    ;  _slk != NULL;  CASTEQ(_slk,_slk->slk_next)

#include <ovrlib/slk.proto>

CDEFEND

#endif
```

Comment: I don't think your whole-structure content swap has the right effect on the links.  Suppose we start with PRED <--> X <--> Y <--> SUCC (by object identity) and we use your swap to exchange X and Y.  I think that yields a broken result with PRED --> X --> SUCC and PRED <-- Y <-- SUCC (again, in terms of object identity).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Oops. I was just riffing off Ian's comment about doing `freq` too, Useless's comment about `swap(LNodeStruct&, LNodeStruct&)` and OP's comment about how to do it. I can adjust the top part of the answer

Comment: ... and of course, since the OP's list is double-linked, one would need to save and restore the `prev` pointers, too.  That's totally doable, but by the time one gets it done, they will probably find that it would have been easier and clearer to swap around the links.  Link Swapping (TM): not just for mergesort any more!

Comment: @JohnBollinger From your TM, I'm assuming your old enough to remember Anita Bryant's Florida orange juice commercials :-) I missed the fact that OP's code was doubly linked [I'm pre-coffee, sigh]. The singly linked code above was actually created from my doubly linked code and I just commented out the `prev` link fixup in the outer function. I haven't benchmarked maintaining the `prev` links on the fly instead of the O(n) fixup, so I honestly don't know if the extra code complexity is worth it vs. possible extra cache misses on the extra/separate pass.